# Loop through database and display them in new file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this script that loops through the database and displays all of it's contents.

```
$select_report = $conn->prepare("SELECT test_db FROM report");
$select_report->execute();
while ($result_report = $select_report->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   echo $result_report["test_db"];
}
```

My question is, can I create a HTML file that has the looped content?
I tried using this script but it only displays the last row in the generated HTML file.

```
$select_report = $conn->prepare("SELECT test_db FROM report");
$select_report->execute();
while ($result_report = $select_report->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   $html_report = "
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <title>Sales report</head>
                </head>
                <body>
                  <div class='container'>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                           <tr>
                             <th>test</th>
                           </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                             <th>". $result_report["test_db"] ."</th>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
               </body>
               </html>
                  ";
$myfile = fopen("report - ".date("m, d, s").".html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $html_report);
fclose($myfile);
}
```

IMAGE:

[generated html table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ8FK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all a matter of just looping the items (in this case table rows) that need to be looped:

```
$select_report = $conn->prepare("SELECT test_db FROM report");
$select_report->execute();
$html_report = "
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <title>Sales report</head>
                </head>
                <body>
                  <div class='container'>
                    <table>
                        <thead>";

while ($result_report = $select_report->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
   // concatenate rows
   $html_report .= "<tr>
                             <th>test</th>
                           </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                             <th>". $result_report["test_db"] ."</th>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>";
}
// outside of loop    
$html_report .= "</table>
                  </div>
               </body>
               </html>
                  ";

$myfile = fopen("report - ".date("m, d, s").".html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

fwrite($myfile, $html_report);
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are recreating the table for each row. Only the TR part in the body needs to be manipulated.

Comment: I just wrote that as an example. It's not the "real" HTML structure. Even tho I tried it by echoing the script and it worked. All content were looped and displayed but when I generated the HTML file, it only took the last row and displayed it